# Can I substitute water instead of oil in a box cake mix

Tags: cake

Can I substitute water for oil in a box cake mix?

Comment: No. You can use applesauce to replace some of the oil, but using just water will likely not yield something you want to eat.

Comment: Nope, chemistry don’t work that way.

Comment: You can, but you won't get anything resembling cake, so you shouldn't. If you want cake, anyway.

Comment: Perhaps edit your question to include details of what you are trying to achieve by substituting the oil with water.   Maybe there *is* something that can help you achieve the desired outcome.   But right now, everyone is guessing.

Answer (score 1):

A cake needs a binding agent to hold the moisture. Mimi had a great suggestion using applesauce. If that isn’t what you’re looking for, there are other oils. You can use olive oil (use a lighter tasting one) or use coconut oil. I’ve used coconut oil myself, and it worked out great.

Answer (score 0):

Yes.  Water can be substituted for oil in a box cake mix.  However, the texture of the final result will be impacted.  Oil adds to the moisture and richness of the cake. So you can expect a drier result.  Suggestions like using applesauce, yogurt, or something like mashed banana can add moisture back.  But, you can still bake it and achieve a cake, albeit a drier one, with water rather than oil.